# Having difficulty writing to two files at once

Tags: python, for-loop, file-writing

Hello wonderful people of the internet.

I am having difficulty writing to two files at once. The code I am using looks like this. I would be grateful for any help.

```
with open("solutionnoiseoneonemode.txt", "w+") as solution, open("projectionononemode.txt", "w+") as projection:

    solution.write("%s " % 0)
    for j in np.arange(Nx):
        if j % 10:
            solution.write("%e    " % x[j])
    solution.write("\n")

    projection.write("%s " % 0)
    initialp = np.matmul(projectionmatrix,q0)
    print("initial p")
    print(initialp)
    projection.write("%e    " % initialp)
    projection.write("\n")

    solution.write("%s " % 0)
    for j in np.arange(Nx):
        if j % 10:
            solution.write("%e    " % q[j])
    solution.write("\n")


    for i in range(np.int(T)):
        print(i)
        tstep = i*timestep
        print(tstep)
        #print(q)
        qnew = np.matmul(inverted, (q - timestep * (q ** 3) + beta(x)))
        qproj = np.matmul(projectionmatrix, qnew)
        print(qproj)

        if i % 10 == 0:
            solution.write("%s " % tstep)

        for j in np.arange(Nx):
            if j % 10 == 0:
                solution.write("%e    " % q[j])

        solution.write("\n")
        q = qnew
```

Nothing comes out in the projection file!! This is super annoying.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file? Try using an absolute path and double check what the working directory is.

Comment: Hey, I am new to this. What do you mean by absolute file? x

Comment: Absolute path means the full path from the root of your drive to the file (like `C:/Users/Name/Desktop/somefile.txt`). `"projectionononemode.txt"` is a relative path, meaning it's referring to a file location, *relative* to the current working directory.

Comment: okay will check :)